# Ошибка операндов

Tags: python, рекурсия

Переустановил `python` и `ide`, теперь даже самый простой код ошибки вызывает. Что делать?

> unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'.

```
def F(n):
    if n < 3:
        return 1
    elif n > 3:
        return F(n - 2) * F(n // 3)

print(F(16))
```

Comment: `F(3)` возвращает `None`. Переустановка Питона и средств разработки не помогает от логических ошибок в коде. :)

Comment: а как исправить? это код из ответов задания ЕГЭ, должно работать все (наверное)

Comment: А какой результат вы хотите получить, когда n равен 3?

Comment: я же 16 передаю в алгоритм, а к 3-м не получится прийти, число же всегда увеличивается

Comment: `n - 2` и `n // 3` — число всегда уменьшается. `16 // 3 → 5`, затем `5 - 2 → 3`

Comment: можно 2 и 3 строки на else: заменить, но тогда в ответ все время 1 возвращать будет, но ответ другой

Comment: Ну так а какой ответ вы хотите-то для n = 3?

Comment: там для n = 3 нет условия, или больше, или меньше 3. все

Comment: Ну тогда задачу решить невозможно

Comment: "но ответ другой" - а какой ответ?

Answer (score 1):

В вашей рекурсивной функции не обработан случай, когда `n == 3`, из за этого функция в одну из своих итераций **возвращает пустоту** (тип `'NoneType'`), а в последующую ошибку:

> unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'.

Так как мы не можем использовать математические операторы с типом, который не поддерживает их.

Чтобы избежать этого, вам нужно учесть этот факт, что `n` может быть **равно 3**

```
def F(n):
    if n <= 3:
        return 1
    elif n > 3:
        return F(n - 2) * F(n // 3)

print(F(16))
```

или же просто поменять `elif` на `else`

```
def F(n):
    if n < 3:
        return 1
    else:
        return F(n - 2) * F(n // 3)

print(F(16))
```

Comment: *мы не можем использовать математические операторы с типом, который не является числовым* - знаки математических операций могут быть валидными не только с числовыми типами, например, строки

Comment: @splash58, спасибо, немного поправил ответ)